# Await for the user choice in AlerDialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

How can I wait for the  user choice, I tried many approaches like this one: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/1554 but doesn't work.
My code:

```
 import {
  AlertDialog,
  AlertDialogBody,
  AlertDialogContent,
  AlertDialogFooter,
  AlertDialogHeader,
  AlertDialogOverlay,
  Button,
} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil"
import { unTitleTag as unTitleTagAtom } from "../../atoms/controls"

export function AlertDelCreateCancel({ isOpen, onClose }) {
  const [unTitletag, setunTitleTag] = useRecoilState(unTitleTagAtom) 
  //setunTitleTag(1)

  function deleteTag() {
    setunTitleTag(2)
    onClose()
  }

  return (
    <>
  <AlertDialog
    isOpen={isOpen}
    onClose={onClose}
    closeOnOverlayClick={false}
  >
    <AlertDialogOverlay>
      <AlertDialogContent backgroundColor="dark.background">
        <AlertDialogHeader fontSize="lg" fontWeight="bold">
          Your Region
        </AlertDialogHeader>

        <AlertDialogBody>
          Are you sure you want to exit....?
        </AlertDialogBody>

        <AlertDialogFooter>
          <Button onClick={cancelAnswer}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button colorScheme="red" onClick={deleteTag} ml={3}>
            Delete 
          </Button>
          <Button colorScheme="red" onClick={createEmptyTag} ml={3}>
            Create Empty
          </Button>
        </AlertDialogFooter>
      </AlertDialogContent>
    </AlertDialogOverlay>
  </AlertDialog>
</>
```

)
}

And I'm calling this AlertDialog from other component:

```
const {
  isOpen: isAlertOpen,
  onOpen: openAlert,
  onClose: closeAlert,
} = useDisclosure()...
openAlert()
if (unTitleTag === 1) {
        return
} else if (unTitleTag === 2) {
        //delete
        setTags((prev) => prev.filter((s) => s.id !== tagSelected.id))
}....
<AlertDelCreateCancel onClose={closeAlert} isOpen={isAlertOpen} />
```

....

Please help, I need to wait for one of the choices: Cancel, Delete, Create, but the program continues immediately after the AlertDialog (modal) is called.

Comment: I used this approach and it's working fine: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/71267740/7458200](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71267740/7458200)